# Not able to handle iframe and new window activity

Tags: iframe, ide, selenium, popup, handle

I am not able to handle Iframe popups. In my application when i click on some buttons or link then open iframe pop up. activity which i do on that iframe popup is not recorded in selenium IDE.
select window command also not work.
When i click on link then it open in second window with same title. i am not able to handle that new window's activity.
Please provide me solution if any have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the command Select Frame and not Select Window.